# Regular expression, value in between quotes

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a little trouble constructing the regular expression using java.

The constraint is, I need to split a string seperated by !. The two strings will be enclosed in double quotes. 
For example:

```
"value"!"value"
```

If I performed a java split() on the string above, I want to get:

```
value
value
```

However the catch is value can be any characters/punctuations/numerical character/spaces/etc..

So here's a more concrete example. Input:

```
""he! "l0"!"wor!"d1"
```

Java's split() should return:

```
"he! "l0
wor!"d1
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see that question here already, but it really should have been one of the first to be asked: Can you describe the use case for this split? Where does the string to split come from? Maybe there's a better way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression: `(".*")\s*!\s*(".*")`

Although it would not work with split, it should work with `Pattern` and `Matcher` and return the 2 strings as groups.

```
String input = "\"  \"he\"\"\"\"! \"l0\" ! \"wor!\"d1\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\".*\")\\s*!\\s*(\".*\")");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.matches())
{
  String s1 = m.group(1); //"  "he""""! "l0"
  String s2 = m.group(2); //"wor!"d1"
}
```

Edit:

This would not work for all cases, e.g. `"he"!"llo" ! "w" ! "orld"` would get the wrong groups. In that case it would be really hard to determine which ! should be the separator. That's why often rarely used characters are used to separate parts of a string, like `@` in email addresses :)

Comment: `(".*")` matches everything between two double quotes. This alone would match the whole string, so you take it twise and put the `\s*!\s*` in between, meaning that both groups must be separated by "any whitespace, exclamation mark, any whitespace". A requirement for this to work would be that you have only 2 strings separated that way. If you don't know the number of strings things would get much harder.

Comment: When you say "any whitespace, exclamation mark, any whitespace", I've tried eliminating the whitespaces between the exclamation mark and the regex still works, why is this so?

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy language, I meant "any number of any whitespace", i.e. no whitespace at all would still match, i.e. `\s` = any whitespace, `*` = any number (0 or more)

Comment: What do you mean? `"he"!"llo"!"world"` is matched as well: `"he"!"llo"` and `"world"` - ok, actually it wouldn't work the other way round, so in this case it would really be hard to decide whether to split on the first or second exclamatin mark.

Comment: Whoops error on my part. Attempted to delete message before you got to it but guess you saw it before I deleted. :) Since there are two instances of \"!\" in the string, I am wondering how does the reg ex know to match it with the second \"!\"?

Comment: Well, as I already said, this wouldn't work if the first "!" should be matched. The regex matches the second one because of the greedyness of `".*"`, i.e. it tries to match as much as possible before coming to the `\s*!\s*` part.

Comment: So as the two poster below mentioned, I'm guessing regex is not the approach to solving this problem?

Comment: @user459811 Do you know yourself what kind of split must be done in weird cases or not ? We can't build a regex without understanding what is aimed at. In the following cases, what must be the results? ``""he! a!::e" !"mn"! "l0"de!"wor!"d1"`` , ``""he! a!::e"!"mn"! "l0"de!"wor"d1"`` ,  ``"he"!"g "l0"!"wor"!"d1"!"jhg1"!"n"!"kiu`` , ``"he"!"g "l0"!"wor"!"d1"!"jhg1"!"n"!`` , ``"he"!"g "l0"!"wor"!"d1"!"jhg1"!"n"`` , etc..;

Comment: That's my question. As I mentioned above, the exclaimation point is the seperator between two words that are enclosed in double quotes. "value"!"value". So it would seem the split would be on ! or "!". The catch is, value can be any character/punctuation/number which is why if there are embedded "!", the solution becomes difficult. In weird cases, I dont know of any way of telling where to split.

Comment: If you as a human can't determine where to split the string in weird cases, the computer can't either (it is only as intelligent as its programmer ... bla bla ;) ). So your foremost goal in this case should be to simplyfy the problem by putting some constraints or rules on it, e.g. if the string is entered by a user, escape each entered exclamation mark. Thus you could distinguish between those entered by the user and those added by the system.

Answer (score 2):

have the value split on "!" instead of !

```
String REGEX = "\"!\"";

String INPUT = "\"\"he! \"l0\"!\"wor!\"d1\"";

String[] items = p.split(INPUT);
```

Comment: What if the two string has an embedded "!"?         i.e. "he"!"llo"!"world"?

Comment: The problem falls out of regular expression territory and you would need to use a parser of some kind to crawl the string in order to break it up.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you need to parse on:

```
DOUBLEQUOTE = "
OTHER = anything that isn't a double quote
EXCLAMATION = !
ITEM = (DOUBLEQUOTE (OTHER | (DOUBLEQUOTE OTHER DOUBLEQUOTE))* DOUBLEQUOTE
LINE = ITEM (EXCLAMATION ITEM)*
```

It feels like it's possible to create a regular expression for the above (assuming the double quotes in an ITEM can't be nested even further) BUT it might be better served by a very simple grammer.

This might work... excusing missing escapes and the like

```
^"([^"]*|"[^"]*")*"(!"([^"]*|"[^"]*")*")*$
```

Another option would be to match against the first part, then, if there's a !and more, prune off the ! and keep matching (excuse the no-particular-language, I'm just trying to illustrate the idea):

```
resultList = []
while(string matches \^"([^"]*|"[^"]*")*(.*)$" => match(1)) {
    resultList += match
    string = match(2)
    if(string.beginsWith("!")) {
        string = string[1:end]
    } elseif(string.length > 0) {
        // throw an error, since there was no exclamation and the string isn't done
    }
}
if(string.length > 0) {
    // throw an exception since the string isn't done
}
resultsList == the list of items in the string
```

***EDIT:** I realized that my answer doesn't really work. You can have a single doublequote inside the strings, as well as exclamation marks. As such, you really CAN'T have "!" inside one of the strings. As such, the idea of 1) pull quotes off the ends, 2) split on '"!"' is really the right way to go.*

Comment: The regular expression does not appear to work for me. How would I go about refining a grammar in java? Is there a special library?

Comment: Honestly, I've never used grammers in java, but I'm sure there's a library for it. Thinking over my answer, your best bet might be to just work on the regular expression and implement the (while matches, prune and loop) algorithm.